# How to open chrome(multiple) + profile + webpage and to click ob button of webpage

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to Like my Video on tiktok then i make this code

```
Console.WriteLine("how many Broswer u want to open");
int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("put ur URL");
String RKS = Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("ID or Name of Button to Click");
string ALB = Console.ReadLine());

if (y == 1){ 
  Process.Start("C:\\Program files\\Google\\chrome.exe",RKS + "-Profile-directory=deafult" )
}
```

https://vm.tiktok.com/ZMN2jb2GQ/?k=1
how to click like button of this page
any code
thanks for help

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for something that can used for automated browser testing of sites. May be Selenium with ChromeDriver! But, as it stands, we're not sure what your specific issue is.

Comment: now i can open many chrome with different profile with specific Url example how to open 10 chrome with url www.google.com and click search button of google it is clear?

Comment: Yes, but your question is not really specific enough for [so]! Are you having trouble opening 10 instances, opening the site in the browser, or clicking the like button. We need more detailed and specific info.

Comment: let me explain my code is just to open multiple chrome(installed in my pc)with diferent chrome profile and to put any URL my prb is how to click in button of web page that i opened